# Flask Login not working after migrating to Azure

Tags: python-3.x, azure, flask, csrf, flask-login

After trying for a week to fix the issue I decided to post the question here.

I migrated my application (python+flask) from cloud foundry to Azure.
After that suddenly my user login and registration functionalities stopped working.
After checking a bit more, at first, it was displaying an error message that my CSRF token was invalid.
I disabled CRSF globally to test. The registration function was working again, however, the login functionality was still odd. I showed 4 kinds of behavior:

1 - accessing the Login page directly and inserting the right email and password redirects you to index, as intended, but current_user.is_authenticated = false;

2 - accessing the Login page and inputting the wrong password or email returns you to the login page but with no alert that password or email was wrong;

3- accessing a page behind login requirement and using the right email and password will just reload the login page with the redirect in the URL and do nothing;

4 - same as 3 but with wrong password or email results in the same thing;

After a while, I enabled the CSRF again and now the error message changed to CSRF token missing.

Maybe it is not related, but the issues began after I migrated to Azure (it worked in the beginning, but it stopped working after a while...I can't remember if it was before or after I started enforcing HTTPS).

Here is my code:

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
import os
from flask_login import LoginManager
from itsdangerous import URLSafeTimedSerializer

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = os.getenv('MAIL_SERVER')
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = os.getenv('MAIL_PORT')
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.getenv('MAIL_USER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD')
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('MYSQL_URI')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(32)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = os.getenv('SERVER_NAME')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)
migrate.init_app(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
login = LoginManager()
login.init_app(app)
login.session_protection = "strong"
login_serializer = URLSafeTimedSerializer(app.secret_key)

from app import views, models

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

on models.py:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print("User loader called with id %s" % user_id)
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
```

my forms on views.py:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password2 = PasswordField(
        'Repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different email address.')
```

my login, register, and logout functions on views.:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    print(form.errors)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    flash('Login Failed')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form, is_auth=current_user.is_authenticated)


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = RegistrationForm()
    print(form.errors)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User(email=form.email.data)
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Congratulations, you are now a registered user!')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', title='Register', form=form)
```

my login template:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block body %}
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <div class="box box-default">
            <div class="box-body">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <p>
                        {{ form.email.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.email(size=64) }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if form.errors %}
                        {{ form.errors }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ form.password.label }}<br>
                        {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                        <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if form.errors %}
                        {{ form.errors }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <p>{{ form.remember_me() }}
                           {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
                        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
                    </form>
                <p>New User? <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Click to Register!</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

my register template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <div class="box box-default">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <p>
                    {{ form.email.label }}<br>
                    {{ form.email(size=64) }}<br>
                    {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if form.errors %}
                    {{ form.errors }}
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {{ form.password.label }}<br>
                    {{ form.password(size=32) }}<br>
                    {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if form.errors %}
                    {{ form.errors }}
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
                <p>
                    {{ form.password2.label }}<br>
                    {{ form.password2(size=32) }}<br>
                    {% for error in form.password2.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if form.errors %}
                    {{ form.errors }}
                    {% endif %}
                </p>
                <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I apologize in advance if the code doesn't look professional, I'm still a junior and a bit new with flask.

Does anyone see what might be causing the described issue?
I'm using python 3.8, flask 1.1.2, flask-wtf 0.14.3, and flask-login 0.5.0.

I tried everything from the other similar questions on StackOverflow and from this [blog](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask), but nothing worked so far or seems to be related to my issue (so please consider this before marking this question as a duplicate).

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

edit: grammar

Comment: how is a database ?

Comment: The database is a mysql db for Azure. The table for the user data has 3 columns: Id, email, password_hash.

Comment: did you use domain to access login page or ip address ?

Comment: Domain, if I understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with Miguel Grinberg about the issue and he pointed out the problem was with:

```
 app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(32)
```

This part of the code was making so, every time the app was restarted the tokens would be invalidated.
I just changed it to a static environment variable and it is now working fine again.